# Drag&Drop from listbox 2 dbedit with comma seperated values and no duplicates

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have made my `listbox` properties to `dbautomatic` and `multiselect` to true.

```
procedure TForm2.Edit1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
Accept := True;
end;

procedure TAuftragsVerteilewaehlen.Edit1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
          Y: Integer);
begin
         (Sender as TEdit).Text := (Source as TListBox).Items [(Source as TListBox).ItemIndex]
        end;
```

The problem I have is, I could get only one value. How could i get multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to iterate all items in the `TListBox` and check the [Selected](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.Selected) property.

```
s := '';
for i := 0 to (Source as TListBox).Items.Count - 1 do 
  if (Source as TListBox).Selected[i] then  // Do your stuff with Item
    s := s + (Source as TListBox).Items[i] + ',';
SetLength(s,Length(s)-1);
(Sender as TEdit).Text := s;
```

---

If you want to avoid duplicates, add each item to a `TStringList` with `Sorted` property set. Set the `Duplicates` property to fit your needs and handle possible exceptions.

Comment: MyList.Sorted := True; // To keep them sorted 
  MyList.Duplicates := dupIgnore; // To ignore the duplicates
Thanks and i have used the above properties like you have suggested.